# After install antivirus nod32 on windows 8.1, I can't edit hosts file

Tags: administrator, hosts, nod32

My problem:
I installed nod32 and after that I can't edit hosts file on windows 8.1 - window appears "Access denied". Of course I've opened hosts file as administrator by notepad. I don't know where is problem or how to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

## Temporary workaround

If you just need to do a one-time change to your `hosts` file, you might *briefly* disable the [Host-based Intrusion Protection System (HIPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_prevention_system) provided by the antivirus:

1. Open NOD32, and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to access the **Advanced setup** dialog.
2. Navigate to the **Computer > HIPS** section.
3. Uncheck the **Enable HIPS** option, and restart Windows to apply the changes.
4. Apply the required changes. When done, follow steps 1-3, and enable HIPS again.

**Note** In case you need frequent read/write access, consider configuring a specific allow rule instead (see the links below). For troubleshooting purposes you can enable the **Log all blocked operations** option, which is available in the HIPS advanced settings.

### Further reading

- [What is HIPS (Host-based Intrusion Prevention System) in ESET Smart Security/NOD32 Antivirus?](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2950)
- [HIPS - Advanced setup](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2908)